# How to import a class from another package

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am new to python, please can someone help me to import class from another package. not from another module.

WorkFlowManager.py

```
from views.MainView import MainScreen


class WorkFlow:
    MainScreen()
```

workflow class is under controllers package

MainScreen is under views package and MainView module.

when i try to import mainscreen from mainview module and views package. it throws me the following error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "WorkFlowManager.py", line 1, in ?
ImportError: no module named views
```

Comment: is there a \_\_init\_\_.py file in your dir where views.py lives in? If not. Create one

Comment: views is a directory.

Comment: The views directory should have a `__init__.py` in it then.  It doesn't need to have anything in it, but for python to detect the directory as part of the package, it needs to have `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your `views.py` is in a directory present in `sys.path`. If it isn't, probably the simplest thing is to add that directory to your `PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem looks like in your python path. The interpreter doesn't know about views. Make sure you export your pythonpath. Something like this in your terminal.

```
export PYTHONPATH="/Users/<user>/project_location"
```

EDIT:

to make it permanent add to your

```
~/.bashrc  
or
~/.bashrc_profile  

export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/my/other/path
```

Comment: What if he wants it to persist? What if he's not using a mac?

Comment: Any UNIX system, same for distros of linux. Plus python on windows is garbage - so I assume the best. No need to hate Marcin.